# react-apollo gql, TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo

I have a `App` component that I am wrapping into a apollo provider:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { observer, Provider } from "mobx-react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";

// graphQL
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import { setContext } from "apollo-link-context";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";

import Main from "./components/Main/Main";
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation/Navigation";

import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: "myUri"
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
  const token = "myToken";
  // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null
    }
  };
});

const mozaikClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

@observer
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <ApolloProvider client={mozaikClient}>
          <Provider {...this.props.stores}>
            <Router>
              <div className="app-container">
                <Navigation />
                <Main />
              </div>
            </Router>
          </Provider>
        </ApolloProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Then I have the About component that I want to consume the provider data:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { gql, graphql } from "react-apollo";
class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>About component.</div>;
  }
}

const landingPageQuery = gql`
  query landingPage {
    documents(types: [LANDING]) {
      items {
        id
        ... on LandingDocument {
          landingPortrait {
            id
            url
          }
          greeting
          content
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default graphql(landingPageQuery)(About);
```

I am getting the following error:

> About.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>       at Object../src/components/About/About.js (About.js:10)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 9e0e85e19ef23447e3e2:669)
>       at fn (bootstrap 9e0e85e19ef23447e3e2:87)
>       at Object../src/components/Main/routes.js (routes.js:1)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 9e0e85e19ef23447e3e2:669)
>       at fn (bootstrap 9e0e85e19ef23447e3e2:87)
>       at Object../src/components/Main/Main.js (Contact.js:4)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 9e0e85e19ef23447e3e2:669)
>       at fn (bootstrap 9e0e85e19ef23447e3e2:87)
>       at Object../src/App.js (zen-observable.js:498)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 9e0e85e19ef23447e3e2:669)
>       at fn (bootstrap 9e0e85e19ef23447e3e2:87)
>       at Object../src/index.js (Skills.js:4)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 9e0e85e19ef23447e3e2:669)
>       at fn (bootstrap 9e0e85e19ef23447e3e2:87)
>       at Object.0 (styleVariables.js:17)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 9e0e85e19ef23447e3e2:669)
>       at bootstrap 9e0e85e19ef23447e3e2:715
>       at bundle.js:719

Where and why is this error coming from, and what does it mean? It is pointing to the line where I am defining my query using `gql`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This seems like a known issue - see [here](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/1273).
Try installing `graphql-tag` and importing `gql` from this library.

Comment: Yeah, seems the docs are not updated properly - but the migrating from 1.0 to 2.0 docs are. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the curly brackets.

Instead of:

```
import { gql } from 'graphql-tag';
```

Do

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you some of you still have the same issue, try to import it with `apollo-boost`

`import { gql } from 'apollo-boost'`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that I was importing useQuery from react
`import React, { useEffect, useState, useQuery } from 'react'`

Changed to

`import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client'`

and everything worked.